# Separate date vector containing several names and dates into separate name and date vectors in R

Tags: r, date, vector, character

I have a `date` vector containing several names with corresponding dates. For example:

```
lastUpdate <- as.Date(c(RMO = 18659, NKLA = 18659, JD = 18659, AAPL = 18901, 
                        IBM = 18901, SPCE = 18659, MRNA = 18901, MPNGF = 18659),
                      origin = "1970-01-01")
```

However, I would like to separate `lastUpdate` into its corresponding names vector (i.e., `character` class) and dates vector (i.e., `Date` class). Manually it would for example be:

Manually extracting is possible, but tedious (especially if the list is longer):

```
lastUpdateSymbols <- c("RMO", "NKLA", "JD", "AAPL", "IBM", "SPCE", "MRNA", "MPNGF")
lastUpdateDates <- as.Date(c(18659, 18659, 18659, 18901, 18901, 18659, 18901, 
                             18659), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

My question:

- With (preferably) only the `System Libraries`, what code could automatically separate `lastUpdate` into `lastUpdateSymbols` containing only the names (i.e., `character` class) and `lastUpdateDates` containing only the dates (i.e., `Date` class) **whilst respecting the order/correspondence** of the content of object `lastUpdate`?

Thanks in advance.

---

Systems used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 and macOS Big Sur version 11.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Use `enframe` after which `frame$name` and `frame$value` give the two parts or use it with `with(frame, ...)`  where `...` is any expression that uses `name` and/or `value`.

```
library(tibble)
frame <- enframe(lastUpdate); frame
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  name  value     
  <chr> <date>    
1 RMO   2021-02-01
2 NKLA  2021-02-01
3 JD    2021-02-01
4 AAPL  2021-10-01
5 IBM   2021-10-01
6 SPCE  2021-02-01
7 MRNA  2021-10-01
8 MPNGF 2021-02-01
```

**2)** or extract each into a variable (no packages):

```
Names <- names(lastUpdate)
Values <- unname(lastUpdate)
```

Comment: Solution 2) is what I was looking for. Works perfectly. Thanks G. Grothendieck!

Answer (score 0):

lastUpdate.df <- as.data.frame(lastUpdate)

lastUpdateSymbols <- rownames(lastUpdate.df)

lastUpdateDates <- lastUpdate.df$lastUpdate